# Why is this JavaScript function producing this output?

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code:

```
var MyObject1 = function (a, b) {
      return {
         myA : a,
         myB : b,
        hello : function () { return "Hello !"; }
       } ;
     } ;
```

...and `obj1 = MyObject1(1, 2)` will result in `obj1` being set to `{myA: 1, myB: 2, hello: ƒ}`, but I don't understand why it is producing this value.

Also, why does `obj1.myA;` remain the value `1`? Is it because `hello` is a closure?

Comment: What did you expect the result to be? If not 1 then what is expected result?

Answer (score 1):

> I write

```
obj1 = MyObject1(1, 2) // {"myA" :1,"myB" :2}
```

> Can someone explain me why?

Cause `MyObject` is a function that returns an object, therefore if you call it it returns an object :)

> when I write:

```
 obj1.myA;
```

> why does the answer remain 1, it is because hello is a closure?

Cause you created a new object, and that object has got a property `myA` which was set to `1` during construction. Then you assigned that new object to the global variable `obj1`, so you can access it whenever you want. Closures are only involved if you got a function inside another function, for example if you would do:

```
 var MyObject1 = function (a, b) {
  return {
     myA : a,
     myB : b,
    hello : function () { return a; }
   } ;
 } ;
```

Then `a` is closured inside `hello`, so you can do:

```
MyObject1(1,2).hello() // 1
```

Comment: I understand,but why when I write: obj1 = MyObject1(1, 2) it only outputs : {"myA" :1,"myB" :2} but not the hello key also?

Comment: @alicia don't let the output confuse you, methods just disappear when you log them (i guess youre on a node REPL)

Comment: @JonasW. Technically `.hello` is not a method. [Methods in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) is different than normal functions. I would call it a "callable property". A normal function can be used as a constructor (such as `MyObject1.hello`), while a method cannot.

Answer (score 0):

basically lets check all the code:

`var MyObject1 = function (a, b) {}`

this is a `function` assignation, you can redefine this as

`function MyObject1(a,b){}`

lets continue with the `return` statement of the function

`return { ... }`

here you are returning an `Object` so it would be what you will have assigned on the variable that you are assignating with the return of your function.

`let obj1 = MyObject1(1, 2)`

here we can see that you are assigning the `return` of the `MyObject1(1,2)` to the `obj1` variable, and the `return` is an `object` that you build dynamically each time that you call `MyObject1`.

and at the end you ask why `obj1.myA;` is `1` right? this is easy, you created and object with the following properties based on the parameters of the object construction, in this case `(1, 2)`:

```
{
    myA: 1,
    myB: 1,
    hello: function()
}
```

this it is clear why the value of `obj1.myA` is `1`.

```js
var MyObject1 = function(a, b) {
  return {
    myA: a,
    myB: b,
    hello: function() {
      return "Hello !";
    }
  };
};

let obj1 = MyObject1(1, 2);
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1.myA);
```