# Javascript Closure code

Tags: javascript

I have a question about this fonction:

```
var MyObject3 = function (a, b) {
   var obj = { myA : a, myB : b } ;
   obj.foo = function () { return obj.myA + obj.myB ; } ;
   obj.bar = function (c) { return obj.myA + c ; } ;
   return obj ;
} ;
```

obj.foo and obj.bar are closures(what i understand). I write first:

```
 obj3 = MyObject3(1, 2) ;
```

and the result is: `{"myA" :1,"myB" :2}`. This is OK.  I try to change the value of obj3.myA : > obj3.myA = 4 ; obj3 ; and the result is : `{"myA" :4,"myB" :2}` . What I don't understand is: why `> obj3.foo() ;` returns 6? obj3.foo() gives 6 as a result ? obj3.foo() is supposed to be a closure isn'it ? its result should be;3 ?

Comment: Is this today's homework? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493579/closures-javascript/50493663

Comment: Thought the code looked similar. lol

Comment: Don't be so angry folks. Understanding the basic theoretical concepts is sometimes the most difficult part, there's nothing bad about asking questions

Comment: @NikitaIsaev Oh, no anger or hostility intended at all. You're correct that understanding the basics can be challenging but the road to knowledge is one of exploration, not outsourcing.

Comment: @FissureKing chances are, on his own he would finally come to an incorrect understanding

Answer (score 1):

Function `MyObject3` defines a variable in its scope, which refers to a newly created object:

```
var obj = { myA : a, myB : b } ;
```

All references to `obj` inside of that function's scope refer to that object. Than the object is returned by the function and saved to the variable `obj3`. `obj` inside of the `MyObject3` scope and `obj3` in the global scope thus refer to the same object.

In javascript, primitives (e.g. numbers, booleans, strings) are passed by value, whereas objects are passed by reference. Which means that:

```
var val1 = 1;
var val2 = val1;
val1 = 4;
console.log(val2); // will log 1

// but:

var obj1 = {foo: 'bar'};
var obj2 = obj1;
obj1.foo = 'baz';
console.log(obj2.foo); // will log 'baz'
```